# How to plot a Probability Calibration Curve using plotly-python?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, plotly, data-visualization

**Sample Data:**

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X, y = make_classification(
    n_samples=100_000, n_features=20, n_informative=2, n_redundant=10, random_state=42
)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    X, y, test_size=0.99, random_state=42
)
```

I wanted to plot a [Calibration Curve plot](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/calibration/plot_calibration_curve.html) using plotly,Using the below **matplotlib** code as reference

```
from sklearn.calibration import CalibratedClassifierCV, CalibrationDisplay
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier, ExtraTreesClassifier
from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingClassifier, ExtraTreesClassifier

rs = {'random_state': 42}

# ------------------------------------------------------ initiate Classifiers
lgr = LogisticRegression(**rs, max_iter=3000, verbose=True, n_jobs=-1)
mlp = MLPClassifier(max_iter=1000, **rs)
dt = DecisionTreeClassifier(**rs)
et = ExtraTreesClassifier(**rs, verbose=True, n_jobs=-1)
rf = RandomForestClassifier(**rs, verbose=True, n_jobs=-1)
xgb = XGBClassifier(**rs, verbosity=0)
abc = AdaBoostClassifier(n_estimators=100, **rs)
gbm = GradientBoostingClassifier(**rs)
# use_best_model params will make the model prevent overfitting
cat = CatBoostClassifier(iterations=1000, 
                            learning_rate=0.01, 
                            depth=5, 
                            loss_function= 'Logloss', 
                            eval_metric='Accuracy', # 'Precision', 'Recall', 'F1'
                        #  use_best_model=True,
                            silent=True,
                            random_seed=SEED)

clf_list  = [('LogisticRegression', lgr), 
                ('MLP', mlp),
                ('DecisionTree', dt),
                ('ExtraTrees', et),
                ('RandomForest', rf),
                ('XGBoost', xgb),
                ('AdaBoostClassifier', abc),
                ('GBClassifier', gbm),
                ('CatBoost', cat)]

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.gridspec import GridSpec

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 15))
gs = GridSpec(5, 3)
colors = plt.cm.get_cmap("Dark2")

ax_calibration_curve = fig.add_subplot(gs[:2, :3])
calibration_displays = {}
for i, (name, clf) in enumerate(clf_list):
    clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
    display = CalibrationDisplay.from_estimator(
        clf,
        X_test,
        y_test,
        n_bins=10,
        name=name,
        ax=ax_calibration_curve,
        color=colors(i),
    )
    calibration_displays[name] = display

ax_calibration_curve.grid()
ax_calibration_curve.set_title("Calibration plots")

# Add histogram
# grid_positions = [(2, 0), (2, 1), (3, 0), (3, 1)]

grid_positions = [(2, 0), (2, 1),(2, 2),(3,0),(3,1),(3,2),(4,0),(4,1),(4,2) ]
for i, (name, _) in enumerate(clf_list):
    row, col = grid_positions[i]
    ax = fig.add_subplot(gs[row, col])

    ax.hist(
        calibration_displays[name].y_prob,
        range=(0, 1),
        bins=10,
        label=name,
        color=colors(i),
    )
    ax.set(title=name, xlabel="Mean predicted probability", ylabel="Count")

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Here the **CalibrationDisplay** from **scikit-learn** is an object which is added to matplotlib subplot.

```
<sklearn.calibration.CalibrationDisplay object at 0x7f7ee5098850>
```

Is it possible to add the CalibrationDisplay to plotly? How to plot this calibration curve in plotly?